# Java Object null but not throwing exception

Tags: java

I was trying to debug some functionality of code.

It was something similar to this

```
public class Testing {
private JSONArray array;

public void initObjects() {
    this.array = new JSONArray()
}

public JSONArray getArray() {
 return this.array;
}
```

Then i was calling

```
Testing test = new Testing();
System.out.println(test.getArray().toString());
```

I dismissed the fact that the object was null because i would of thought it would of thrown an error if you were calling a method on an object that was null. All that was happening was nothing was getting printed and thats it. It turns out the object was null.

Why is this the case?

Comment: what is `object` here ? in `return object;`, you might be initializing here it somewhere?

Comment: It seems like a simple question, but you're using setObject() first?

Comment: There are two cases (1) `System.out.println(getobject().toString());` is not executed (2) `getobject()` doesn't return null. For better answer post code which will let us reproduce your problem.

Comment: Im not using setObject(). Object was a JSONArray

Comment: i dont have it. I found out it was null going through a debugger.

Comment: @Pshemo - Case (3) - exception is caught in the code not posted.

Comment: @AndrewHenle True, I missed that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, but only unchecked ones. Otherwise it wouldn't compile and throws is needed.

Comment: cant say till you provide complete context to the question. may be toString is returning a null value of some field but not the object.

Comment: @maraca We can also ignore checked exceptions with `catch(Exception e){/*do nothing*/}`.

Comment: @Pshemo still has to be getObject() throws Exception. Probably we are not talking about the same thing.

Comment: Your current code doesn't compile, and if we correct compilation errors it will throw `NullPointerException` so it still can't be used to reproduce your problem. Please take your time and create [short, compilable and correct code example](http://sscce.org/) which we could use to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems that the `object` you returned from `getObject()` is global variable which is initialized somehow. So `object` is actually not *null*.

That's why you get no `NullPointerException` for the following line:

```
System.out.println(getobject().toString());
```

Try this, you will definitely get `NullPointerException` for `getobject().toString()`:

```
public Object getObject() {
 return null;
}
```

**Update:** As the question updated, so I compile the code OP posted:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class Testing {
    private JSONArray array;

    public void initObjects() {
        this.array = new JSONArray();
    }

    public JSONArray getArray() {
     return this.array;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Testing test = new Testing();
        System.out.println(test.getArray().toString());
    }
}
```

and get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Testing.main(Testing.java:16)
```

I downloaded the `java-json.jar` from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm).

Comment: It is a global variable. When i stepped through the debugger it said object was null.

Comment: Please show the minimal code so that we can answer you without any wild guess.

Comment: gobal variables are initialized with null , if they are not initialized specifically ...

Comment: I updated the example. I wasn't calling initObjects() which was the issue.

Comment: @CBaker it may have solved your problem, but the question why this was happening is still unanswered... what if it happens again?

Comment: @CBaker man didn't wanted you to change the checkmark, just curious what's causing it.

Comment: @maraca It seems like the object was getting initialized because it was a global variable which is why it wasnt throwing the exception. I'll have to double check what the value was but the link you sent me seems like what is was getting set to. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CBaker So your question was false alarm, something which will  not be useful for others. That is why people should avoid answering such questions and ask author for code which will let them reproduce it, so in case of not-real-problem question could be easily deleted.

Comment: Answers saying ["it must work" or "it works for me" are not real answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid) because they don't provide solution, nor explanation to *the* problem because (a) it was false alarm, so there wasn't real problem to begin with (b) it simply means that we can't understand real problem and OP should provide more informations.

Comment: @Pshemo, I understand your point, although I posted the answer before OP updated the question with new code, where I indicate where OP was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned on one of comment object is a json array. so toString method of jsonarray might return blank in case it is empty but initialized .

this is what is reads in javadoc

toString()

public java.lang.String toString()

```
Make a JSON text of this JSONArray.
```

so you need to check where your is being initialized , if you are using eclipse you can references having cursor on object and press ctrl + shift + g.

Answer (score 0):

After editing the question there is a possible explanation:

`JSONObject.NULL` the constant is not the same as `null`, you have to compare the return value of `getObject()` with `JSONObject.NULL` using `equals`.

Comment: what is JsonObject.NULL the constant?

Comment: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html see here, it is just an object representing a null value (usually this is done to make a difference between null (JSONObject.NULL here) and not defined (actual null)).